# Why does my code keep giving me errors when I run it? It compiles just fine

Tags: java, loops

I'm new to java and I have an assignment to count #s, @s, and links in tweets. So I wrote this program and the compiler doesn't see any errors, but when I run it and enter a tweet, it'll give me errors.

```
 public static void main (String str[]) throws IOException {
      Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

      System.out.println("Please enter a tweet.");
      String tweet=scan.nextLine();
      int quantity = tweet.length();
      System.out.println(tweet);
      if (quantity > 140)
      {
        System.out.println("Excess Characters: " + (quantity - 140));
      }
      else{
        System.out.println("Length Correct");
        int hashtags=0;
        int v=0;
        if (tweet.charAt(0)=='#'){
        hashtags++;
        v++;
        }
        String teet=tweet;
          while (hashtags != v-1){
          v++; 
          int hashnum= teet.indexOf('#');
          if ((teet.indexOf('#')!=-1) && (teet.charAt(hashnum + 1)!=(' ')) && (teet.charAt(hashnum-1)==(' '))) {
             hashtags++;
          }
          if (teet.indexOf('#')!=-1) {
          teet=teet.substring((hashnum+1),(quantity));
               }
          }
        System.out.println("Number of Hashtags: " + hashtags);
        int ats=0;
        int w=0;
        if (tweet.charAt(0)=='@'){
          ats++;
          w++;
        }
        String tweat=tweet;
        while (ats != w-1){
          w++;
          int atnum= tweat.indexOf('@');
          if ((tweat.indexOf('@')!=-1) && (tweat.charAt(atnum + 1) !=(' ')) && (tweat.charAt(atnum-1)==(' '))) {
            ats++;
          }
          if (tweat.indexOf('@')!=-1) {
          tweat=tweat.substring((atnum+1),(quantity));
          }
        }
        System.out.println("Number of Attributions: " + ats);

 }
 }
 }
```

Thanks to anyone who can help.

Comment: It'll give you errors huh? Which errors?!

Comment: are you given any lines or traces as to where or what the error is?

Also, your formatting is difficult to read.

Comment: When I type #hi, it'll say this:

Comment: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
 at java.lang.String.charAt(Unknown Source)
 at twitter1.main(twitterassignment.java:33)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at edu.rice.cs.drjava.model.compiler.JavacCompiler.runCommand(JavacCompiler.java:272)
>

Comment: That error is telling you that you're trying to read a char in the String that is at a larger position than your String's total length. When it says "java:33", that's telling you that the error occurs at that line so look in detail at that.

Comment: Test it with the string: tweet #twohashtags #fail!  The error occurs when you do the second substring call when you assign "teet" the rest of the tweet.

Answer (score 0):

String.indexOf(String) method will return 0 for the first character.
The exception is thrown at :

```
teet.charAt(hashnum - 1)
```

since hashnum is 0, what you're doing is "#hi".charAt(-1).